# помогите понять как работает элемент canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

на [сайте](https://landing.tooligram.online/)

есть элемент с кнопкой play, сделал html код и css а желтый круг не получается сделает думаю каким то скриптом сделано

Comment: смотри [тут](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/)

Comment: мне нужно с ихнего сайта

Comment: Боюсь, это писалось руками, без библиотек. Либо использовались библиотеки общего назначения, типа [anime.js](https://animejs.com/), [pixi.js](http://www.pixijs.com/) и т.д.

Comment: я вроде нашел какой файл это делает но что конкретно взять не понимаю по  этому прошу помощи https://landing.tooligram.online/js/main.min.js?v=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сайте используется [эта](https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress) библиотека для создания круга.

```js
var circle = $('#circle')

circle.circleProgress({
    value: 0.75,
    size: 80,
    fill: "#fdba45",
  });

circle.mouseover(function() {
 circle.circleProgress('value', 1);
})

circle.mouseleave(function() {
 circle.circleProgress('value', 0.75);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-circle-progress/1.2.2/circle-progress.min.js"></script>

<div id="circle"></div>
```

С настройками и стилями, надеюсь, вопросов не возникнет

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста а можно что бы круг заполнялся при наведении на блок в целом а не на этот элемент

Comment: сделал тут https://xn----8sbbqciguqh1bit.xn--p1ai/

Comment: @ЭлвинАлиев если ответ был полезным, за него можно проголосовать

Comment: подсказать еще можете?

Comment: @ЭлвинАлиев да, конечно. Что Вас интересует?